# How to load correctly a string from asset html file in a webview

Tags: android, html, webview, assets

I have an html file in asset folder and i would like to load it in a webview. I would like to use the string, and not the file in order to replace the content of file when i want (keep only one file and change the content i want to display).
For example my html file is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<p data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="dYPxYp" data-default-tab="html,result" data-user="sckarolos" data-embed-version="2" data-pen-title="SVG Shape Example" class="codepen">
    See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/sckarolos/pen/dYPxYp/">SVG Shape Example</a>
    by sckarolos (<a href="https://codepen.io/sckarolos">@sckarolos</a>) on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="https://production-assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I have these two methods for reading the html file from assets as string and load it in a webview:

```
private String getHtmlFromAsset() {
        InputStream is;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String htmlString = null;
        try {
            is = getAssets().open(htmlFilename);
            if (is != null) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                htmlString = builder.toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return htmlString;
    }

    /**
     * Loads html page with the content.
     */
    private void loadHtmlPage(WebView webView) {
        String htmlString = getHtmlFromAsset();
        if (htmlString != null) {
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "No such page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And in my activity i use webview like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

         //try to display html content
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        loadHtmlPage(webView);
      }
```

On debuging i can see that my file read successfully and my string has the content of html file. But when i am trying load it in webview, the result is nothing. If i try to load the local html file using this:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myFile.html");
```

then the file loads and displays successfully.
I suppose that my fault is in the way i use the string that i take back from getHtmlFromAsset and pass in loadHtmlPage.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try this `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");` I think if you use `null` then it will resort back to 'about:blank'.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried using "" instead of null in loadDataWithBaseURL method as you said but it is not working, the result is still the same,  an empty webview.

Answer (score 0):

Here, code pan required javascript access so when link load you need to provide javascript access. this is working code also check into my emulator. Also, don't forget to give internet permission on the manifest.

**XML:**

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**JAVA:**

```
String str = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
        "<html>\n" +
        "<head>\n" +
        "    <title>This is demo</title>\n" +
        "</head>\n" +
        "<body>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "<p data-height=\"265\" data-theme-id=\"0\" data-slug-hash=\"dYPxYp\" data-default-tab=\"html,result\" data-user=\"sckarolos\" data-embed-version=\"2\" data-pen-title=\"SVG Shape Example\" class=\"codepen\">\n" +
        "    See the Pen <a href=\"https://codepen.io/sckarolos/pen/dYPxYp/\">SVG Shape Example</a>\n" +
        "    by sckarolos (<a href=\"https://codepen.io/sckarolos\">@sckarolos</a>) on <a href=\"https://codepen.io\">CodePen</a>.</p>\n" +
        "<script async src=\"https://production-assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js\"></script>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "</body>\n" +
        "</html>";
WebView wv = findViewById(R.id.wv);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        // do your handling codes here, which url is the requested url
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false; // then it is not handled by default action
    }
});
wv.loadData(str, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. The result again is an empty webview. Did you try the code and managed to get the content displayed in the webview?

Comment: @Zapas here, this code may also try and is working pretty. can you try this one?

Comment: Hello, i just tested your code but still does not work. It keeps giving me back empty webview. I try to understand what I'm doing wrong. The only way i could load the html file is using **webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myFile.html")**. As string always getting empty webview.

Comment: I copied the string that getHtmlFromAsset method returns in a notepad and saved it as html file. I run  the html file in browser and displays correctly. So i think that my fault is in the way i try to pass the string in the webview.

Comment: I tested the code in emulator (genymotion) and in real device (Huawei P9 Lite) but as a result i get only the code before javascript **(See the Pen Switch Button # 2 by sckarolos (@sckarolos) on CodePen)** with no javascript functionality above. In your test did you manage to see this result [link](https://codepen.io/sckarolos/pen/GpgVJv) in the webview? I believe that i miss something in the way that i have to use the javascript in my html file after reading it as string.